# Authenticate OSX Server Users via PHP

Tags: php, macos, authentication

I am running `OSX Server` on a MacMini in our office.
The Users (created with the OSX Server App) are used for authenticating the *SMB* and *VPN* service.

Now i would like the users to login in our intranet-app via PHP.

Are there any possibilities to access the OSX Server Users?
Does it work in other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web server is running on the same Mac Mini (or another Mac server that is attached to the same OD server), you can use browser authentication to control access and then use the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable from php to determine which user is logged in.

To set this up, you're going to need to enable login on the Websites control panel in the Server App and then specify which users are allowed to access the site ('Who can access' in the web site information panel).

For security purposes, make sure you use SSL so that your password exchanges are protected from prying eyes, although by default I'm pretty user you at least get Digest authentication instead of Basic, which is a little better.

If you prefer not to use the web server security, you're going to have to jump through some hoops to authenticate, most likely involving using LDAP to talk to the Open Directory server on the Mini.  In the old days, you used to be able to use LDAP authorizations to validate passwords against the OD server, but I'm not sure if that still works.  Either way, it's a lot of work.